# Supervisor: no such file or directory even though it is there

Tags: shell-script, executable, supervisord

I am trying to start supervisor `service supervisor start`, as root, but it gives me

> env: /etc/init.d/supervisor: No such file or directory

Yet, I can clearly see that file exists:

> [root@master vagrant]# ls -l /etc/init.d/                    total 256
>
> -rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  2062 Oct 17  2014 atd
>   -rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  3378 Jun 22  2012 auditd
>   -rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  2826 Nov 23  2013 crond
>   -rw-r--r--. 1 root root 18586 Oct 10  2013 functions
>   -rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  5866 Oct 10  2013 halt
>   -rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 10804 Nov 23  2013 ip6tables
>   -rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 10688 Nov 23  2013 iptables
>   -rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root   652 Oct 10  2013 killall
>   -r-xr-xr-x. 1 root root  2134 Nov 23  2013 lvm2-lvmetad
>   -r-xr-xr-x. 1 root root  2665 Nov 23  2013 lvm2-monitor
>   -rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  2989 Oct 10  2013 netconsole
>   -rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  5428 Oct 10  2013 netfs
>   -rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  6334 Oct 10  2013 network
>   -rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  6364 Nov 22  2013 nfs
>   -rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  3526 Nov 22  2013 nfslock
>   -rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  3852 Dec  3  2011 postfix
>   -rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  5383 Mar 30 08:29 postgresql
>   -rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  1513 Sep 17  2013 rdisc
>   -rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  1822 Nov 22  2013 restorecond
>   -rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  2073 Feb 22  2013 rpcbind
>   -rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  2518 Nov 22  2013 rpcgssd
>   -rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  2305 Nov 22  2013 rpcidmapd
>   -rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  2464 Nov 22  2013 rpcsvcgssd
>   -rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  2011 Aug 15  2013 rsyslog
>   -rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  3085 May 11 21:07 salt-master
>   -rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  3332 May 11 21:07 salt-minion
>   -rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  1698 Nov 22  2013 sandbox
>   -rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  2056 Feb 27 15:57 saslauthd
>   -rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root   647 Oct 10  2013 single
>   -rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  4534 Nov 22  2013 sshd
>   **-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  1345 Jun 11 10:20 supervisor**
>   -rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  2294 Nov 22  2013 udev-post
>   -rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 15634 Mar  7  2014 vboxadd
>   -rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  5378 Mar  7  2014 vboxadd-service
>   -rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 20887 Mar  7  2014 vboxadd-x11

And it contains some script, as expected.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I disagree that this is a duplicate of the marked question. In the marked question, it was clear that something about the first line of the script was wrong, whereas here, it was not clear (at least to me) where the error even was. The benefit of the answer to this question is stating that the error is in the first line. Only with this knowledge given is the linked question helpful. However I agree it is closely related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not complaining about the `/etc/init.d/supervisor` file itself, but most likely about the file it wants to execute as - usually the shell that appears on the shebang line in that file. It's a somewhat misleading error that I've seen many times before.

Comment: That was /bin/bash... but the file for some reason had windows newlines, and that's why /bin/bash^M wasn't found!? Thanks, that was it! :-) I think the problem is that I checked out a git repo on windows and used the files in a Linux VM, probably the line endings were changed at check-out. I need to check the rest now...

Comment: Yeah, ^M's are what usually pop that error message up for me, too. That's why I'm so appreciative to whomever wrote `dos2unix`.